# jQuery form.id vs form.id.value

Tags: javascript, jquery, dokuwiki

I'm working on dokuwiki plugin and I've found interesting think about how js stores element id. I'm not sure what is going on... So I have a code from dokuwiki linkwiz.js file which is using to determine if ':' char is in the part of the id string:

```
    dw_linkwiz.textArea = $editor[0];

//some code between

    // prepend colon inside namespaces for non namespace pages
    if(dw_linkwiz.textArea.form.id.value.indexOf(':') != -1 &&
       link.indexOf(':') == -1){
       link = ':' + link;
    }
```

the $editor is the jQuery object. As you can see to get id of the element they uses form.id.value but in some cases when I setting id of the element dynamicly using jQuery .attr method, the form.id.value is undefined and the id string is simply kept in form.id . Do you know why it happes? Which is more standard compilant?

Comment: If `dw_linkwiz.textArea` is a jQuery object, then `.form` should be `undefined` I think

Comment: Is there a field in that form whose "name" attribute is "id"?  That's what would make sense to me, and it would mean that `form.id.value` is fetching the "value" property of the input field named "id".

Comment: @ExplosionPills note that the jQuery object is dereferenced: `[0]`

Comment: @Pointy oh, silly me.  I thought he meant `$editor[0]` itself was the object

Comment: Actually I'm starting to think that's just a bug.

Comment: @Pointy you've got it. There is a filed named "id". I can't believe it.

Comment: @hafron wow that's ... not a good idea :-)  It means that the actual "id" property that should be on the form DOM element is gone, which I suppose doesn't really hurt anything but I wouldn't do it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Normally a DOM elements id will be a string and not an object, so `form.id` will be a string with the `id` value.  It shouldn't be an object with a value.  This plugin may have defined another object with an id property that contains a value property, but thats not a standard DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

id in this case is not the id attribute of an element, but a field named "id" in the form.

Simplified it looks like this:

```
<form>
<input name="id" value="some:page">
<textarea>the editor</textarea>
</form>
```

`dw_linkwiz.textArea` is the DOM object of the textarea. `dw_linkwiz.textArea.form.id.value` is "some:page".